# VBA RegEx match email

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

Simple question here, just looking for a function that will check if an input is an email.

I have a form in Microsoft Access where the user inputs an email address (optional), so if they enter a value for email address I want to check to make sure it's in an email format, like an alphanumeric character followed by "@" followed by another alphanumeric character. I think there are also some additional requirements for an email address like no special characters besides an underscore and ending in ".com" or dot something.
Function should look something like this:

```
Function isEmail(eml As String) As Boolean
    Dim emailRegEx as New RegEx
    emailRegEx.Pattern = (\w[@]+\w[.]\w\w\w)

    If (emailRegEx.Test(eml) = True) Then
        isEmail = True
    Else
        isEmail = False
    End If
End Function
```

I'm surprised MS Access doesn't have an option for *email* input mask, so I guess this has to be done in code until they add that feature. Hopefully this isn't a duplicate, I've seen this question in other programming languages and questions like email domain check in VBA, but haven't seen this exact question asked in VBA.

Comment: So is the question how to implement email verification by regex in Access VBA, or what is the regex pattern for email verification?

Comment: Question is how to implement email verification by regex in Access VBA. The Regex pattern is the main piece of the puzzle needed to accomplish this.

Comment: Try this one `^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$`, I found it somewhere on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work, I tested it out with some valid and invalid email addresses.

```
Function isEmail(sEmail As String) As Boolean
    Dim regexEmail As New RegExp
    regexEmail.Pattern = " (^\w+)([.]*)(\w*)[@](\w+)[.](\w+$)"
    regexEmail.IgnoreCase = True
    isEmail = regexEmail.Test(sEmail)
End Function
```

'explanation: ^\w+ begins with one or more letters, numbers, or underscores.

'[.]* may or may not include a dot (for example firstName.LastName@live.com)

'\w* may or may not include one or more letters, numbers, or underscores.

'[@] exactly one @ symbol

'\w+ one or more letters, numbers, or underscores.

'[.] exactly one dot

'(\w+$) ending with one or more letters, numbers, or underscores.

If anyone sees something I missed here I welcome any suggestions to improve this solution. Note for anyone attempting to implement this solution: you will need go to Tools >References and add reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions to use RegEx in your app.
Credit to Kamarapush and [officeTricks.com](https://officetricks.com/validate-email-address-vba-code-excel/) since I adapted code from their page.

Comment: Hi. Check out my answer, I think you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub test()
    Const csMail As String = "abcd@defg.com"
    Debug.Print isEmail(csMail)
End Sub


Function isEmail(eml As String) As Boolean
' needs reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions
    Dim emailRegEx As New RegExp
    emailRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    emailRegEx.Pattern = "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}"
    isEmail = emailRegEx.test(eml)
End Function
```

There will be different RegEx depending on how far you will go; see [regular-expressions.info/email.html](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks martin, I like how you did the last line there, I will use that in my solution to eliminate the need for the If/Else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Unbeknownst to many people, the plus sign is actually allowed in the username of email addresses. This is called "plus addressing" or "subaddressing". Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/plus-addressing-in-exchange-online).

While the accepted solution works for most valid email addresses it fails for the test string,

```
"The email address,'Mary-Jo.T.Williamson_01+test@test-site.com', is contained within this string".
```

, which contains a perfectly valid email address with examples of all types of allowed characters.

The following function has another RegEx pattern which works for all valid email addresses:

```
Function isEmail(sEmail As String) As Boolean
    Dim regexEmail As New RegExp
    
    regexEmail.pattern = "[a-z0-9-.+_]+@[a-z-]+\.[a-z]+" ' new RegEx pattern
    regexEmail.IgnoreCase = True
    isEmail = regexEmail.Test(sEmail)
    
End Function
```

Read more [here](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-regex-regular-expressions-guide/). (Disclosure: I'm the author of the article).